# Jumping jee-willigers: sqlite3 GUI browser for Windows?

Tags: sqlite

Is there such a thing ? I'd really like to be able to browse my sqlite 3 databases. Can't seem to find any useful tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good open source GUI SQLite database managers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)

Answer (score 1):

You mean a tool like [SQLiteAdmin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it in a while, but there's [sqlitecc](http://sqlitecc.sourceforge.net/).  Also, there's [dbedit2](http://dbedit2.sourceforge.net/features.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually browse SQLite databases with Visual Studio's built-in server explorer. All you need is the free [SQLite.NET driver](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

> Visual Studio 2005/2008 Design-Time Support
>
> You can add a SQLite
>   connection to the Server Explorer,
>   create queries with the query
>   designer, drag-and-drop tables onto a
>   Typed DataSet and more! SQLite's
>   designer works on full editions of
>   Visual Studio 2005/2008, including
>   VS2005 Express Editions.
>   * NEW You can create/edit views, tables, indexes, foreign keys,
>   constraints and triggers interactively
>   within the Visual Studio Server
>   Explorer!

(Works with VS2010 as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there would be a good one, right? A few months back, I had to use one a lot. Everything I tried (all the free ones I could find) were awful, the least awful being sqliteman (http://sqliteman.com/). It's still pretty bad, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/). While not free, it's a excellent tool. Also look for SQLite Administrator.